# Looping through dictionary and TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int' - Python

Tags: python

I want to return a new dictionary with letter grades substituted for the number grades

90 for an A, 80 for a B, 70 for a C, 60 for a D. Anything below 60 is an F.

Example:

letter_grades({'Bob' : 55, 'Joe' : 90, 'Martha': 86}) returns {'Bob' : 'F, 'Joe' : 'A', 'Martha': 'B'}

I have written

```
def letter_grades(adict):
    """
    Parameter adict: the dictionary of grades
    Precondition: adict is a dictionary with string keys, int values
    """
    for a in adict:
        for i in adict.values():
            if i >= 90:
                adict[a] = 'A'
            elif i >= 80:
                adict[a] = 'B'
            elif i >= 70:
                adict[a] = 'C'
            elif i >= 60:
                adict[a] = 'D'
            elif i < 60:
                adict[a] = 'F'

    return adict
```

When I input letter_grades({'wmw2' : 55, 'abc3' : 90, 'jms45': 86})

I get an error saying:

TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

can someone tell me why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try something like this. Use `adict.items()` to look both the keys (`k`) and values (`i`). And a good idea is to include an `else` even though it does nothing (or you can raise an error in case the data is bad).

```
def letter_grades(adict):
    """
    Parameter adict: the dictionary of grades
    Precondition: adict is a dictionary with string keys, int values
    """
    for k, i in adict.items():
        if i >= 90:
            adict[k] = 'A'
        elif i >= 80:
            adict[k] = 'B'
        elif i >= 70:
            adict[k] = 'C'
        elif i >= 60:
            adict[k] = 'D'
        elif i < 60:
            adict[k] = 'F'
        else:
            pass

    return adict

print(letter_grades({'wmw2' : 55, 'abc3' : 90, 'jms45': 86}))
```

Output:
`{'wmw2': 'F', 'abc3': 'A', 'jms45': 'B'}`